# Display a contantly updated text file in a web user interface using Python flask framework

Tags: python, shell, flask

In my project workflow, i am invoking a sh script from a python script file. I am planning to introduce a web user interface for this, hence opted for flask framework. I am yet to figure out how to display the terminal output of the shell script invoked by my python script in a component like text area or label. This file is a log file which is constantly updated till the script run is completed.

The solution i thought was to redirect terminal output to a text file and read the text file every X seconds and display the content. I can also do it via the Ajax way from my web application. Is there any other prescribed way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use [HTML Server-sent events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) (in python you would use *redis-py* and it's [PUB/SUB capabilities](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub)). That way you create a one-sided connection to server. Your web client will wait until you send response from server, which may be for example two minutes later, with no timeout. It's called long polling and it's much more efficient way than asking every 5 seconds if there is any change. Of course, reading from a shell is another matter to discuss.

Comment: It's probably better to direct the terminal output to a pipe (with your app owning the other end of the pipe), instead of directing it to a file and reading that file. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457175/how-to-read-a-file-that-is-continuously-being-updated-by-appending-lines/25457311#25457311) for why you reading a file is harder than reading a pipe, socket, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The one way I can think of doing this is to refresh the page. So, you could set the page to refresh itself every X seconds.

You would hope that the file you are reading is not large though, or it will impact performance. Better to have the output in memory.